# how can I add the http command to netsh?

Tags: windows-server-2003, netsh

In the [msdn docs for ssl configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx), there's this command:

`netsh http show sslcert`

But on my machine (Server 03) I don't have httpcfg command (looked in many places), `netsh` doesn't have the http sub-command. How can I get the http sub-command to show up? I've tried using AddHelper with all the http*.dll's I could find. No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN docs say for Windows Server 2003, you've to use `httpcfg query ssl`.

If you httpcfg is not available, you will have to install [Windows Server 2003 support tools](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Windows_2003_Support_Tools.html).
`netsh http show sslcert` is for Vista.

Comment: Well httpcfg isn't available on my machine but netsh is.

Comment: Looks like it has to be added to the OS - HttpCfg.exe ships with the operating system starting with Windows Server 2003 as a binary executable, together with a help file that describes how to use it. It can be installed from the operating-system distribution disk as a support tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364478(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Dsolimano - yes, it needs to be installed from support tools - just updated @jcollum

Comment: For the task I'm trying to complete, it'd be preferable to use netsh. I don't want code in my codebase that is dependent on the installation of a support tool when (if) I could simply use netsh instead.